# Can't fetch data from Express server to React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from the server to display some articles. While the Postman returns the array of objects and  http://localhost:5000/articles displays it just fine, when i fetch to React the screen is blank and there are no errors.
There is a snippet from server.js

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser')
const cors=require('cors');
const app=express();

const db=require('./db');
const articleController=require('./controllers/article-controller');
const userController=require('./controllers/user-controller');
const postController=require('./controllers/post-controller');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser())

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error'))

//get /articles
app.get('/articles',articleController.get)

app.use('/',userController)

app.listen(5000, ()=>
    console.log('Server started on port 5000')
);
```

Here is the ArticleService.js file from the client

```
export default {
getArticles: ()=>{
     return fetch('http://localhost:5000/articles')
        .then((response, error)=>{
            if(response.status !== 401){
                console.log(response)
                return response.json().then(data => data)
            }
            else{
                console.log(error)
                return {message:{msgBody:"Error"}}
            }
        })
}}
```

And the Article.jsx component:

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Navbar, Footer} from '../components'
import ArticleService from '../Services/ArticleService'
import {AuthContext} from '../Context/AuthContext'

const Articles=props=>{
//const [article, setArticle]=useState({title:"", content:""})
const [articles, setArticles]=useState([])
const authContext =useContext(AuthContext)

useEffect(()=>{
    ArticleService.getArticles()
        .then(data=>{
            setArticles(data.articles)
        })
},[])

return(
    <div>
        <header>
            <h1>Articles</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
        <ul className="list-group">
            {
                articles && articles.map(article => {
                return(
                    <li key={article._id} article={article}>
                    <h1>{article.title}</h1>
                    <p>{article.content}</p>
                    </li> 
                )
                })
            }
        </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
)
}

export default Articles
```

I'm also not getting any errors in the console.Just the response with the type: "cors", status: 200 and ok: true

Comment: Suggest you read a bit more about CORS, this a very common thing when communicating from browser to a server. Do check for more of the same before raising the question. There are probably existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add the CORS middleware and configure your browser application server or allow all

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Read more about the CORS, check this out

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS